# NOAA API data for past monthly mean Temperature and precipitation

Tags: python, data, api, weather, noaa

I am trying to use the NOAA API to get data on monthly mean temperature and precipitation for the past 10 years. I wrote the following python code (the variable "token" in the code is the API token that I got:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCNDMS&locationid=ZIP:28801&startdate=2000-01-01&enddate=2010-01-01"
response = requests.get(url, headers = token) 
data = response.json()
```

I am not able to get data for for the specified time period. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Wild speculation: too much data requested? What happens if you try 1 year or even 1 month?

Comment: what response do you get?

Comment: I am getting the average  monthly temperature data but its for only one month. I don't know why I am unable to get the rest of the data. Even if I try to get data for a few months, I still end up getting data for the first month.

Answer (score 4):

From the looks of it, you are getting a python error [because the headers argument is expecting a dictionary](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request), not a string

The following works for me on the entire date range:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCNDMS&locationid=ZIP:28801&startdate=2000-01-01&enddate=2010-01-01"
# replace 'myToken' with the actual token, below
headers = {'token': 'myToken'}
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
response = response.json()

# the beginning of the response
{u'results': [{u'date': u'2000-01-01T00:00:00', u'datatype': u'CLDD', u'station': u'GHCND:USW00013872', ...
```

Note: [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) is a useful tool here, too:

```
curl -H "token:myToken" "http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCNDMS&locationid=ZIP:28801&startdate=2000-01-01&enddate=2010-01-01"
```

Comment: Yes, I my header is a dictionary with my token information. The data is similar to your data. I don't know how to use curl in python hence I ended up writing the above code. I am having issue with the result that I am getting.  I am getting the average monthly temperature data but its for only one month. I don't know why I am unable to get the rest of the data. Even if I try to get data for a few months, I still end up getting data for the first month. I don't know what I need to do to get the entire data.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out where I went wrong. I forgot to set my limit for the data, so by default the limit was set up to be 25. This was the reason why I was getting data just for the first month. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was also getting a response limit of 25. I added &limit=50 to the end of the url and all is good now.